# git-blame with spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, magit

I'm trying invoke magit-blame in spacemacs. If I do:

```
SPC g b
```

Then I see a "git-blame" section at the bottom which says:

```
Press [_b_] again to blame further in the history, [_q_] to go up or quit.
```

But if I hit `b`, I see the error message:

```
Unbound suffix: 'b'
```

ON the other hand, if I invoke magit blame instead by doing:

```
M-x magit-blame
```

And then I hit `b`, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented in Spacemacs and [#13643 Add Git Blame Transient State](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/13643) sounds like it would probably fix this, on `develop`.